# Return transactions for a specific pair - TheGraph

Tags: query, graphs, the-graph

I am trying to return the latest 1000 transactions for a specific pair in Uniswap V2 using The Graph playground.

The pair I am using is for USDC/WETH and its id is: `0xb4e16d0168e52d35cacd2c6185b44281ec28c9dc`

The query I wrote is:

```
query {
  transactions(
    orderBy: timestamp,
    orderDirection: desc,
    first: 1000,
    where: {
     swaps_not: [""],
     mints_not: [""],
     burns_not: [""]
    }
  )
  {
    swaps(where: {
      pair: "0xb4e16d0168e52d35cacd2c6185b44281ec28c9dc"
    }) {
        transaction{
         id
      }
    }
    mints(where: { pair: "0xb4e16d0168e52d35cacd2c6185b44281ec28c9dc"}) {
        transaction{
         id
      }
    }
    burns(where: { pair: "0xb4e16d0168e52d35cacd2c6185b44281ec28c9dc"}) {
        transaction{
         id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**HOWEVER**

It still returns some swaps or mints or burns which are empty and thus without transaction. How to I return only the transactions of swaps/mints/burns which are not empty?
[image]